# Javascript select random option

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've got problem with this code:

HTML:

```
<div class="select">
     <select name="ipd" id="ipd">
        <option value="1">192.168.2.1</option>
        <option value="2">192.168.2.2</option>
        <option value="3">192.168.2.3</option>
        <option value="4">192.168.2.4</option>
        <option value="5">192.168.2.5</option>
     </select>
    <a href="#" onclick="myfunction()">Select random</a>
</div>
```

And JavaScript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function myfunction() {
    var select = document.getElementById('ipd');
    var items = select.getElementsByTagName('option');
    var index = Math.floor(Math.random() * items.length);

    select.selectedIndex = index;
}
</script>
```

When i'm remove function line from JS and made code to run after site load it's work fine. But when i'm trying use it in  it doesn't work.
Can someone explain me why? 
I try to little debug this and add alert(index) to the function and it's return correct random index, but it don't select anything.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/n7k63smf/ seems to be working fine

Comment: you'll just want to make sure your function is available when the dom is created... in the above jsfiddle your function is placed in the head

Comment: Hm.. it's look it doesn't work in my html theme.  But code for this it's same in head.

Comment: Yeah, when i'm put it in some divs and form it doesn't work. Without it work fine. Any ideas? And thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code works fine... as long as it is ran before the DOM is created.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/n7k63smf/)

---

If your script is getting ran after the DOM is created and you can't change that for whatever reason... you could remove the onclick in the DOM, add an ID on the link and do it this way instead:

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/n7k63smf/1/)

```
document.getElementById("randomSelect").addEventListener("click", function() {
    var select = document.getElementById('ipd');
    var items = select.getElementsByTagName('option');
    var index = Math.floor(Math.random() * items.length);
    select.selectedIndex = index;
});
```

---

Also, I noticed you tagged jQuery, you could also use that...

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/n7k63smf/2/)

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#randomSelect").click(function () {
        var select = document.getElementById('ipd');
        var items = select.getElementsByTagName('option');
        var index = Math.floor(Math.random() * items.length);
        select.selectedIndex = index;
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks, but it's still doesn't work in my theme. I put JS/jQuery code in head and put code in some divs, checked that id=ipd isn't used anywhere and still nothing. When i move select from divs it's work fine. Do you know what can make these problems?

Comment: You made sure the `$("#randomSelect")` in the code matched the `id="randomSelect"` on the `<a>`? i don't really understand by what you mean with putting code in some divs and what you mean by moving select from divs.

Comment: Ok i found something. I have two js script added in head which change select style. When i remove it it works fine, but why it doesn't work with it? URLS: http://pastebin.com/JckCSKpK and http://pastebin.com/UU6Qtkgu

Comment: What do you mean by "change select style"?

Comment: I edited my comments and add these JS files. I don't know what exactly it makes because it's not my own coded theme, just select looks "more friendly" for users (visual changes)

Comment: There is a lot of stuff going on there... you should use chrome or firefox developer tools... make sure "randomSelect" and "ipd" still exist in the dom after it is loaded, check for javascript console errors, and put a debug point in the code to see if the vars are getting assigned what you expect.

Comment: Ok, really big thanks for your help. Have beautiful day!

Answer (score 0):

On clicking the link you page will be reloaded and also the html. So all the dom changes will be lost. You need to stop your page from loading by returning false.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function myfunction() {
var select = document.getElementById('ipd');
var items = select.getElementsByTagName('option');
var index = Math.floor(Math.random() * items.length);

select.selectedIndex = index;
return false;
}
 </script>
```

Comment: with `href="#"` it will not reload the page.

Comment: Thanks, but it still doesn't work. It's work only when i put the HTML code in the body part, but when i put it in the body and inside some divs it's doesn't work.